# specify which jdk to use while having multiple installed

Tags: java, command-line

I have two JDKs installed on my laptop and I want to run a java program using the command line, my environment variables are set and I want to know how the operating system will know which JDK to use because it is not indicated in the command?

```
C:\mywork> javac filenamehere.java
```

Comment: It is determined by Windows through inspection of the `%PATH%` environment variable. The paths are iterated in order, and the executable is searched. The first match will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Windows uses the PATH environment variable to find the first executable with a matching name.
If you want to specify which javac to use, try using the full path to javac.